# How can I change my variant referencing to an input box?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to simplify a file_split script to a point of self-service in my dept. No one really has any understanding of the language, so I was checking to see if any of this could be further simplified so coworkers don't have to update the code from the editor pane.

for instance, I have things like `Basepath` to designate where the files will be saved off. How can I change

```
Dim Basepath As String
Basepath = "C:\Users\File Cuts\" 
directory as string
```

to something like this where a user can select a folder pathway?

```
Dim Basepath as filedialog
with basepath
    .title = "Select save location"
    .directory = .selecteditems(1)
end with
```

and then instances where I have specific columns to reference (target value columns for each new file, naming convention columns, etc...)

as in:

```
Dim Manager_Name, Login_ID, Leader 

Manager_Name = SourceData(i,4)
Login_ID = SourceData(i,5)
Leader = SourceData(i,9)
```

to be inputted by an input box for column letter like:

```
Dim column_selection as variant

column_selection = InputBox("Enter Column Letter") 
Manager_Name = SourceData(i,column_selection)
```

There are quite a few references that I'd like to see if I could change so that edits could be made without actually touching the code (the column ranges where variants like name, and login ID will be changing a lot)

rest of code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub File_Splits()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim SourceData, Mgr_Name, Login_Id
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, a As Long
    Dim Destination_Cell As Range
    Dim Basepath As String, strNewpath As String, strLeader As String
    Basepath = "C:\File Cuts\" '1. paste in file save pathway, keep last \
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\File_Split_Mgr_Template.xlsx") '2. paste template ws address here
    Set Destination_Cell = Wb.Worksheets("Manager Data").Range("A2") '3. Update worksheet name and target cell
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Roster")
        SourceData = .Range("I10", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) '4. change I10 to your last column letter, dont change the number(keep the 10)
    End With
    Wb.Activate
    Call Speed_Up_Code(True)
    For i = 1 To UBound(SourceData)
        If SourceData(i, 5) <> Login_Id Then '5. change the 1 to login column #
            If i > 9 Then
                Destination_Cell.Select

                strNewpath = Basepath & strLeader & "\" 'comment this out if folders aren't needed
                If Len(Dir(strNewpathD, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then 'comment this out if folders aren't needed
                    MkDir strNewpath 'comment this out if folders aren't needed
                End If 'comment this out if folders aren't needed

                Wb.SaveCopyAs strNewpath & _
                ValidFileName(Login_Id & "_" & Mgr_Name & "_File Name.xlsx") '6. update file name
            End If
            With Wb.Worksheets("Manager Data") '7. change to template sheet
                .Rows(2 & ":" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents '8. change 2 to row after header(s)--if header isn't in row 1
            End With
            Mgr_Name = SourceData(i, 4) '9. change 1 to mgr name column
            Login_Id = SourceData(i, 5) '10. change 2 to login ID column
            strLeader = SourceData(i, 9) '11. change 5 to lvl 3 mgr column
            j = 0
        End If
        a = 0
        For k = 1 To UBound(SourceData, 2)
            Destination_Cell.Offset(j, a) = SourceData(i, k)
            a = a + 1
        Next
        j = j + 1
    Next
    If Len(Dir(strNewpath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir strNewpath
    End If
    SaveCopy Wb, strNewpath, Login_Id, Mgr_Name
    Call Speed_Up_Code(False)
End Sub
Public Sub SaveCopy(Wb As Workbook, strNewpath As String, Login_Id, Mgr_Name)
    Wb.SaveCopyAs strNewpath & _
        ValidFileName(Login_Id & "_" & Mgr_Name & "_File Name.xlsx") '12. update file name
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered having a sheet called something like "Configuration" where users write to and your script can read from. Hidden  or protected if necessary

Comment: @CDP1802 could you provide an example? Idk how something like `Mgr_Name = SourceData(i,worksheets("Configuration).columns(2))` would work out

Comment: For example, list all your configuration description in col A, and the user fills in the value next to in col B, So if A1 contains the text "Manager Name Column [A-Z] =" the user enters the value "D" or 4 in cell B1. The script become Mgr_Name = SourceData(i, wsConfig.range("B1")). I guess you could add validation to their entries.

Comment: wow, this actually helps a ton! thank you! Can you post as an answer so I can give credit?

Comment: If you define a function like cfg(s)  which returns  wsConfig.range(s) and make B1 a named range like "MNGCOL" then it could be simply  Mgr_Name = SourceData(i, cfg("MNGCOL")). More readable and allows you to change the layout of the config sheet without having to edit the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered having a sheet called something like "Configuration" where users write to and your script can read from. Hidden or protected if necessary

For example, list all your configuration description in col A, and the user fills in the value next to in col B, So if A1 contains the text "Manager Name Column [A-Z] =" the user enters the value "D" or 4 in cell B1. The script become Mgr_Name = SourceData(i, wsConfig.range("B1")). I guess you could add validation to their entries.

Layout the sheet like a form in logical groups and highlight where the entry cells are. In a case like entering column names I would put them horizontal with the descripting above and entry cell below, that seems more natural. Protect all the cells except the highlighted ones.